Is it possible to ContractMetric while having an unspecified dimension of the manifold
I am doing the contraction of the super-metric with the Ricci tensor, then I want to consider a general case of manifold without specifying the dimensions of the manifold, different from the usual case of 4 dimensions.
DefManifold[M4, 4, {\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma], \[Mu], \[Nu], \[Rho], \[Sigma], \[Tau], \[Kappa], \[Xi], \[Zeta], \[Delta]}]
DefMetric[{3, 1, 0}, Met[-\[mu], -\[nu]], CD, PrintAs ->"g"]

(Met[-\[Gamma], -\[Mu]] Met[-\[Delta], -\[Nu]] + 
   Met[-\[Gamma], -\[Mu]] Met[-\[Delta], -\[Nu]] - 
   Met[-\[Gamma], -\[Delta]] Met[-\[Mu], -\[Nu]])*(RicciCD[\[Mu], \[Nu]] - 1/2*Met[\[Mu], \[Nu]] RicciScalarCD[])
%//ContractMetric

Is it possible to apply the ContractMetric command without specifying the number of the manifold dimension?

You can first define a symbol that represents the dimension:
DefConstantSymbol[dim, PrintAs -> "d"]

and then declare a manifold of that dimension, and a metric:
DefManifold[M, dim, {a, b, c, d}]
DefMetric[-1, g[-a, -b], cd]

You can then use ContractMetric as usual:
In[5]:= g[-a, -b] g[a, b]
Out[5]= dim

In[6]:= g[-a, -b] Riccicd[b, c] // ContractMetric
Out[6]= Riccicd[-a, c]
````

